# How to get date/time when email is opened in office 365 using EWS API?

Tags: email, office365, exchangewebservices

I want to **retrieve email opened date/time** i.e. when the email is actually read.

Is it possible or not using **EWS API**?

In the EWS API there is the flag **IsRead** which is set when email is read so i need to find the date/time when this flag is set to **true**.

If not possible by EWS API is there any other API that can be used to achieve it?

Comment: There is an audit log search in Office365 which log the action like message is viewed or open. But when turned on i am getting an empty search result. Does anyone know why i am getting empty results even after 24 hrs.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible or not using EWS API?

No, it is not.

> If not possible by EWS API is there any other API that can be used to achieve it?

Outlook object model, MAPI and Exchange do not provide information when message was read. It doesn't matter the choice of technology (EWS, REST, MAPI, etc.), message just doesn't have this information. What you able to get is just the flag if message was read.

Comment: Do you know about audit log search in Office365 which i believe can be used to find date/time when message is viewed or open?

Comment: I don't know. This is very limited and uncommon solution to rely on audit logs. At the end, they are logs. Any message can be marked/unmarked with the "read" flag at any time, what's the point to have the time. Anyways, you probably have your own requirements. If the answer satisfy your original question, consider to mark it as the answer.